# What can be the reason Project Planning & Tracking is not working for one project in HP ALM 11.0 when it is working for another project?

Tags: hp-quality-center

Some of our projects use Project Planning & Tracking functionality of ALM. We are facing an issue where the functionality is not working for one project even though it works fine for other projects.

We already did project verify & repair from Site Admin but of no help. Also there are no errors in the logs.

What can be the issue and how can we resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana - Found some schema differences on running the Verify project tool and repaired them with repair tool. After that there is no activity in Logs for that project.